# Android Toggle button doesn't update with view binding when viewModel data is changed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I feel like this is such a simple thing to do but I'm struggling hard to make it work in Android.  All I want is for my toggle button's state (on or off) to be automatically updated when the viewModel changes. I spent four hours on this just this morning :)  I updated to Android Studio 3.6  I have databinding enabled in my gradle file.

```
dataBinding.enabled = true
viewBinding.enabled = true
dataBinding { enabled = true }
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

I added another layout tag to my `activity_main.xml` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <data>
            <variable
                name="userModel"
                type="com.mycomp.myapp.UIViewModel"/>
        </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
    >

Then for my toggle button I have:

     android:checked="@{userModel.isChecked}"
```

And in my viewModel I've tried using either of these methods:

```
public final MutableLiveData<Boolean> checked = new MutableLiveData<>();
public boolean isChecked = true;
```

But no matter what I set isChecked or checked's value to, the toggleButton never changes.  When I start the app it always comes up Off.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainActivity when you are binding this viewModel you should attach lifecycleOwner. It should look like this

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner())
binding.userModel = userModel
```

Comment: thank you, I had to call it like this: binding.setUserModel(userModel);  but this was the piece I was missing!